# Repeat set of mocha tests for two different inputs

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have a feeling I might be thinking about this wrong, but is there any way I can run a set of mocha tests for two different inputs? In my use case, I am parsing data from a pdf and want to run the tests for when the pdf is only one page, and when it is multiple pages.

Right now I am using beforeEach to call my parsePdf function:

```
describe('When parsing a single page pdf', function () {
  beforeEach(function (done) {
    invoiceParser.parsePdf('./test/samples/invoice_singlepage.pdf', function (invoice) {
      this.invoice = invoice;
      done();
    }.bind(this));
  });
  ...
  // tests fields of this.invoice w/ chai.js
  ...
});
```

What I was thinking is I can just parse two invoices before each and check the values of each? Then I have to repeat a lot of code though. Any way to to do this without repeating each test?

Comment: If your code is broken down into good units (functions are separated properly), you shouldn't have to repeat much. Test the units that grab data from the PDF with a mock, test the parser twice, and deduplicate your tests.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for something like dynamically generating tests. Since Mocha the test framework is in Javascript, you can use Javascript logic to define your tests programatically.

https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests

A simple example here:

```
inputs = [
  {
    'name': 'single page',
    'path': './test/samples/invoice_singlepage.pdf'
  },
  {
    'name': 'multiple page',
    'path': ...
  },
  ...
];
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
  describe('When parsing a ' + input.name + ' pdf', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      invoiceParser.parsePdf(input.path, ...
    });
    // test functions go here...
});
```